# Rebuilding LSTM tensorflow model using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello I am new to building models in python and I am trying to learn because I need to train a model using Python and extract its weights and biases to build the model on FPGA

I was following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@curiousily/human-activity-recognition-using-lstms-on-android-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-vi-492da5adef64

I have been trying to implement the same model in the previous link using Keras. However, when I tried to train the keras model the accuracy was 0.0905 eventhough it has the same structure as the tensorflow model.

```
import keras.layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import metrics
import seaborn as sns
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
import pydot as py
RANDOM_SEED = 42

#Reading Dataset
columns = ['user', 'activity', 'timestamp', 'x_axis', 'y_axis', 'z_axis']
df = pd.read_csv('WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt', header=None, names=columns)
df = df.dropna()

#data_preprocessing
N_TIME_STEPS = 200
N_FEATURES = 3
step = 20
segments = []
labels = []

for i in range(0, len(df) - N_TIME_STEPS, step):
    xs = df['x_axis'].values[i:i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    ys = df['y_axis'].values[i:i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    zs = df['z_axis'].values[i:i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    # Note that we take the most common activity and assign it as a label for the sequence.
    label = stats.mode(df['activity'][i:i + N_TIME_STEPS])[0][0]
    segments.append([xs, ys, zs])
    labels.append(label)

#print(np.array(segments).shape)
#(54901,3,200)

reshaped_segments = np.array(segments, dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES)
#print(reshaped_segments.shape)
#(54901,200,3)

# Labels one hot encoding
labels = np.array(pd.get_dummies(labels), dtype=np.float32)
#print(labels.shape)
#(54901,6)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reshaped_segments, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

N_CLASSES = 6
N_HIDDEN_UNITS = 64

model = Sequential()

model.add(
    LSTM((N_HIDDEN_UNITS),input_shape=(N_TIME_STEPS,N_FEATURES),return_sequences=True,recurrent_activation='relu'))

model.add(LSTM(labels.shape[1],return_sequences=False,recurrent_activation='relu'))
print(model.summary())
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0025)
model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=1024)

print(model.get_weights())
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.show()

categories = ['Downstairs', 'Jogging', 'Sitting', 'Standing', 'Upstairs', 'Walking']
max_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
max_predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(max_test, max_predictions)

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 14))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix, xticklabels=categories, yticklabels=categories, annot=True, fmt="d");
plt.title("Confusion matrix")
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()
model.save('mymodel')
```

This is my Keras implemenation, if someone can guide me on what is the difference between both models or if I am missing something I would be very grateful